# Implement a facebook type simpler 'like' feature in backend

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a website made in Django and i want to implement a facebook type (or any social media type) `like` button. I have a `user` table, and a `post` table, and i want users to be able to like the posts. I am confused about some particular things :

- How can I bind user info with likes so that one user can like only one time?

My current approach is:

- I am thinking of creating a new field in `post` table, say `post_likes`, which have list of users who currently like the post. Then, before rendering the 'post' template, i have to loop over all the users (in field `post_likes`) to check if the `request.user` likes the post or not (in views.py), and send that data to template (to change the ui of `like` button to `liked`), but this approach seems very naive to me, also slow. What could be the better approaches?

Comment: Typically you cache the number of likes in an extra field, and update it instantly, or every now and then. You do not have to calculate the likes in Python, but can do so by writing a query for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by creating *two* models: `Post` (that will in reality contain extra data like the `message`, `author`, etc.), and `Like` that is acts as a *many-to-many* relation between a `Post` and a `User`:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='app.Like')

    def like(self, user):
        _, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=user, post=self)
        if created:
            self.total_likes += 1
            self.save()

    @classmethod
    def update_likes(cls):
        cls.objects.annotate(total=Count('likes')).update(total_likes=F('total'))

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So the `like(..)` function is used to *like* a post (with as parameter the user). We can thus call `somepost.like(someuser)`. It will fetch or create a new `Like` object that maps to the specific `post` and the specific `user`. In case the `Like` instance already existed, nothing happend, otherwise we increment the `total_likes` field that stores the total number of likes.

Perhaps you do not want to update this counter every time a user likes a post: after all, it creates some extra load on the server. In that case, the `if created:` part can be omitted, and we regularly should call `Post.update_likes`. This function will perform an aggregate per `Post` that counts the number of likes, and it will update the `total_likes` field.

Regardless whether you update `total_likes` constantly, it is better to every now and then update the total number of likes per post. Since other views, models, etc. can - given you the developers are not looking very strict to this - remove `Like` objects. Furthermore `User`s can be removed, etc. and we have not much control about that. Yes we can create signals that are triggered after `Like`s and `User`s are removed (and created), but still there can be problems with counting the number of likes like *race conditions*. Therefore I would advice to periodically update the number of likes.